# Cypher: Indexing returnInvalid input 'i': expected whitespace comment, ON, '=', node labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is what I am doing. I really don't know what I am doing wrong

> CREATE INDEX index_user FOR (n:User) ON (n.id, n.username, n.email)

The Output is

> Invalid input 'i': expected whitespace, comment, ON, '=', node labels,
>   MapLiteral, a parameter, a parameter (old syntax), a relationship
>   pattern, ',', FROM GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND,
>   MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH,
>   CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 14 (offset:
>   13)) "CREATE INDEX index_user FOR (n:User)"

Comment: Are you sure you are running this exact command? I tried it in a fresh Neo4j 4.0.3 docker instance and it completes without errors: »Added 1 index, completed after 41 ms.«

Comment: I copied the command right off. I am using Graphene db. I guess they use some an older version of Neo4j. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/#administration-indexes-syntax) you are using was added to neo4j 4.x. It is not supported in older versions of neo4j.

In older versions that support composite indexes, like neo4j 3.5, the [syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-composite-index) for creating your index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(id, username, email)
```

*Note: This older syntax is currently still supported in version 4.0.4, but deprecated.*

Comment: Turns out my graphenedb instance was running an old version of Neo4j. Thanks so much. But just to know, are the newer version backward compatible, talking about Cypher commands?

Comment: As I noted, version 4.0.4 still supports the older syntax. But since 4.x deprecates the old syntax, it would better to use the new syntax once you start using 4.x.