# Can't create fulltext index in neo4j 4.2.X

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

According to [this documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.2/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/), in `neo4j` 4.2.X one can create freetext indexes as follows:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX my_index
FOR (n:MYNODETYPE) ON EACH (n.label)
```

Yet when I run this query, I get the following error message:

> Invalid input 'I': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a parameter (old syntax), a relationship pattern, ',', FROM GRAPH, USE GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 17 (offset: 16))
> "CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX my_index"

I've seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412504/cypher-indexing-returninvalid-input-i-expected-whitespace-comment-on) which had a similar error, but the accepted answer says that the syntax I'm using should be valid in `neo4j` 4.X. I'm running neo4j 4.2.7, community edition (confirmed by calling `dbms.components()`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am looking at the docs and they seem a bit different. Try the following:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX titlesAndDescriptions FOR (n:MYNODETYPE) ON EACH [n.label]
```

It seems the above syntax is for Neo4j 4.3+. Syntax for previous versions of Neo4j is as follows:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("titlesAndDescriptions", ["MyNodeType"], ["label"])
```

Comment: Hi Tomaž, I get the same error message as before: `Invalid input 'I': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels, ...` etc.

Comment: which neo4j version are you using?

Comment: I'm running neo4j 4.2.7, community edition, through the official neo4j docker image. At least, that's the version I see when I open localhost:7474 and check `dbms.components()`.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but I use the APOC library too.

Comment: Sorry Tomaž, does this ring a bell?

Comment: The syntax you've posted works as intended, thank you (it is in fact the work-around I'd used). Could you point me to where it says that the syntax is valid for neo4j 4.3+ only? I've only ever found mentions of 4+, not 4.3+...